# How to get issueData from ACC in the furure

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

In the case of the requirement to retrieve an Issue registered in AutodeskConstructionCloud (ACC), I confirmed that the BIM360 API(https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-GET/) can be used to retrieve this Issue.

Currently, I don't think there is a dedicated Issue acquisition API for ACC.
In the future, would it be correct to use the BIM360API for the requirement to retrieve an Issue registered in ACC?

Comment: Issue API for ACC has not been exposed. This AU class tells about the roadmap of ACC API (in 47”). https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Forge-Road-Map-2021#video

Comment: and yes, Issue API of BIM 360 is not compatible with ACC. Sorry for this. If you only want to get Issue data, Data Connector (or API) can be an option. It will extract data to csv. https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-data-connector-api-available-public-beta

Comment: @Xiaodong Liang
Thanks for the reply.   Is it unofficial that the BIM360 API is currently able to retrieve Issues registered with ACC?

Comment: As said , it is not compatible. which means Issue API of BIM360 will not work with ACC project. The engineer team is working on the Issue API for ACC. Hopefully it could come soon. thank you for patience